# GCC creating object files with random suffix when killed

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors

It seems that if GCC is killed at some point during compilation, it will save an in-progress object file to disk. The file has a random suffix of the form `"${hostname}.${PID}.${RandomSuffix}"`. For example  `Thingy.o.linuxVM.31918.WJKwRx`

I can't put an exact date for the start of this, but current version is `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`

This is a frustrating problem as it messes with my ignore globs for my version control system (ie. `*.o`).

Is there any way I can tell `gcc` to stop doing this?

Comment: Maybe just add `*.o.*` to the ignore list?

Comment: Are those files created in current directory? They should go to `/tmp` by default. Are you sure gcc is responsible for them? How does your gcc command line look like?

Comment: @Banthar Definitely happening in current directory. Nothing in the g++ call appears to affect object generation.

Comment: How do you kill (i.e. with what signal)?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid some temporary files by adding `-pipe` option. You can also set environment variable `TMPDIR` to instruct gcc where to create those files and then remove them all.

gcc should clean up after itself, unless you are annihilating it with `SIGKILL`.